# How Can I use This Webview Bar? - Android Stdiuo

Tags: android, webview, gmail

How can I make a bar like the one in the picture? I'd appreciate it if you told me.
Name of the application in the picture: Google Mail

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. I assume you are new to android. But this type of View you can make just by Dialog or Menu View and also there are other way also to make it. but for you I suggest you use Dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm very new to this. This is something that I think Google has given everyone in other applications as well. I saw exactly the same in different applications that don't belong to Google. Do you think it might be open source code?

Comment: If you have Worked on dialog then you can easily do this because you just have to open dialog box on button click